# elapsed time for each rule

Tags: linux, bash, function, makefile

I have this bash code:

(At the start of the script:)

```
function timer()
{
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo $(date '+%s')
    else
        local  stime=$1
        etime=$(date '+%s')

        if [[ -z "$stime" ]]; then stime=$etime; fi

        dt=$((etime - stime))
        ds=$((dt % 60))
        dm=$(((dt / 60) % 60))
        dh=$((dt / 3600))
        printf '%d:%02d:%02d' $dh $dm $ds
    fi
}

t=$(timer)
```

(and, at the end of the script:)

```
printf 'Elapsed time: %s\n' $(timer $t)
```

to calculate the total time elapsed by the script. This code works fine in a bash (shell) script. So, I want to put this code in a makefile for each rule.

How can I put this function in Makefile? And how can call'em in each rule?

I made something like this:

```
define TIME
     stime=$(1)
     etime=$(date '+%s')
     dt=$((etime - stime)) \
     ds=$((dt % 60)) \
     ...
endef
```

and in each rule:

```
rule1: dep1 dep2 dep3
    ...SOME STUFF
    @$(call TIME, starttime)

rule2: depx depD rule1
    ...SOME STUFF
    @$(call TIME, starttime)
```

but the math operation does not work. I tried a lot of things but I can't do works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble is that in your bash script, the variable `t` survives from the beginning (before the work) to the end (when it can be subtracted from the end time). In a Make recipe, each line has its own shell, so a shell variable set in an early line won't be available in a later line.

You could string all of the commands of a recipe together in one line, so that you can set `t` at the beginning and use it at the end, but that's pretty clumsy. I'd suggest you write `t` to a file, maybe `rule1_time`, so that the two calls to `timer` don't require a common variable. Oh, and don't try to use `call` inside a command:

```
STIME = date '+%s' > $@_time
ETIME = read st < $@_time ; echo $$((`date '+%s'`-$$st))

all:
    $(STIME)
    do stuff
    $(ETIME)
```

**EDIT:**
I wrote the code above as a proof of concept; I was going for clarity, not refinement. If I understand your comment correctly, you now want to know how to break down the time into hours, minutes and seconds, without calling several functions from each rule. There are several ways to do it, this is probably the cleanest:

```
ETIME = @read st < $@_time ; st=$$((`date '+%s'`-$$st-68400)) ; echo Elapsed time: `date -d @$$st '+%H:%M:%S'`
```

Comment: thanks. I did your solution but I hoped to do something like a function, more automatized. Now, I have one function (stime, dtime, dt, dh, ...) per math operation needed for the final information.

Comment: The H:M:S calculation is not correct as there is no easy way to display _elapsed_ time using `date`. Timezones, and leap seconds will mess up the output. It is usually necessary to do a successive set of division by 60. Otherwise, fantastic answer. (Comment on a very old post, I know.)

Comment: Also, `date -r <file>` will give you the timestamp of a file, so rather than writing the date to a file and then reading its contents, you could just `touch $@_time` and then do `date -r $@_time +%s` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get timing information for the steps in your build, a better solution is to use a smarter make.  [ElectricMake](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator.php) from Electric Cloud can generate an XML-marked-up version of the build log, called an *annotation file*, which includes the exact timing data for every command invoked by the build, as well a boatload of other information like the exact command-lines used (even if you have used the `@` prefix) and the environment variables used by each command.

You can try it out for free with [SparkBuild](http://www.sparkbuild.com/), a free version of ElectricMake.

Comment: thanks but that I want to do is a part of an application and the timing information need to be displayed on every execution. Our clients want to see this information too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use time:

```
all:
    @@time( \
        rsync -az ${src1} ${dest1} \
        && rsync -az ${src2} ${dest2} \
        ## etc.
    )
```

can't use tabs in here, but remember to use only tabs in makefiles (as POSIX requires that).